# How can I get the weights (kernel) of a Dense layer before Model in Keras?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, autoencoder

```
import numpy as np
from keras import backend as K
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Input
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# download the mnist to the path 
# X shape (60,000 28x28), y shape (10,000, )
(x_train, _), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

# data pre-processing
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255. - 0.5       # minmax_normalized
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255. - 0.5         # minmax_normalized
x_train = x_train.reshape((x_train.shape[0], -1))
x_test = x_test.reshape((x_test.shape[0], -1))


# in order to plot in a 2D figure
encoding_dim = 2

# this is our input placeholder
input_img = Input(shape=(784,))


# encoder layers
encoder = Dense(2, activation='relu')(input_img)

# decoder layers
decoder = Dense(784, activation='relu')(encoder)`
```

I want to know how can I get the weights (such as the kernel of Dense_2) of a Dense layer before `Model` in `keras`?

If i run:`autoencoder = Model(input=input_img,output=decoder)`, then do `autoencoder.get_layer('dense_2').kernel`, I can get the kernel. However, I want to set the kernel as one of the output. So, I must get the kernel before `Model`.

I want to get the `kernel` because it will be set as one part of the loss function, such as `loss2=tf.square(kernel' * kernel, axis=-1)`. So I must get the `kernel` before running `Model`.

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Please do not use the comments space for this kind of additional info - edit & update your post instead

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean you need to have one of your middle layers as one of the outputs.
In your case, you can change your model creation in this way:

```
autoencoder = Model(input=input_img,output=[encoder,decoder])
```

you can define even different losses for each of these two outputs!

Comment: Thanks for your help. In fact, I just want to get the kernel of Dense_2, i.e, decoder. I want to make sure that the kernel is orthogonal. So I designed a penalty function, i.e, loss2, and defined that loss2=tf.square(kernel' * kernel - I, axis=-1).